Django, htmx delete record and update
So I have a list in a partial Django template.
<div class="col">
    <div class="row pb-2" id="rowcolor">
        <div class="col border-bottom">
            pk:{{ color.pk }} / name:{{ color.description|title }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <button hx-delete="{% url 'delete-color' pk=color.pk %}" hx-target="#rowcolor" hx-swap="outerHTML"
                class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm float-end" type="button">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


When deleting the pk149/name3: the pk147 / name1 disappears.
When refreshing it is correct. pk:149 is gone.
The view looks like this:
@require_http_methods(["DELETE"])
def delete_color(request, pk):
    if request.htmx:
        Color.objects.get(pk=pk).delete()

        return HttpResponse("")

I have been trying to read the htmx documentation. But I do not understand. Can anyone please point me in the right direction here?

Don't give items the same id in HTML.

Don't give the same id to multiple elements: make the items unique, for example by adding the primary key to it:
<div class="col">
    <div class="row pb-2" id="rowcolor{{ color.pk }}">
        <div class="col border-bottom">
            pk:{{ color.pk }} / name:{{ color.description|title }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <button hx-delete="{% url 'delete-color' pk=color.pk %}" hx-target="#rowcolor{{ color.pk }}" hx-swap="outerHTML"
                class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm float-end" type="button">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
You can probably slightly boost efficiency of the view by using:
@require_http_methods(['DELETE'])
def delete_color(request, pk):
    if request.htmx:
        Color.objects.filter(pk=pk).delete()
        return HttpResponse('')

Wow! Of course. I now understand that they all had the same ID. So it was always the first div gone then? Thank you so much!
